# return a promise from .apply method

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to promises and trying to **wrap** my head around something that should be simple. Maybe someone can **hit** me in the head with it instead!

I've got these two functions:

```
//an arbitrary method that runs on delay to mimic an async process
    method1 = function( _value, _callback ){
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log('dependency1_resolved');
        _callback.apply(this, [{valIs:_value}]);
      }.bind(this), (Math.random() * 1000));
    };

    //something that can simple return the object
    function returnVal(x){
       console.log(x); //this logs 'Object {valIs: 4}'
       return x;
    }
```

due to it's async nature, I'd like to run this function in a promise to be used later (maybe even chain later) in my code.

here is my promise:

```
var promise = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {
    var x = method1(4, returnVal);
    resolve(x);
  }
);

promise.then(function(val) {
  console.log(val); // undefined
  return val;
});
console.log(promise); //Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

Does this have anything to do with the .apply method in the first function? What am I missing? Can someone please slap me?

Comment: You _can't_ return an async value.  You need to actually pass callbacks.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the `apply`. It has to do with the fact that `method1` does not return a promise. You cannot "later" use that function in a promise

Comment: Or, actually you can, as it takes a callback.

Comment: thanks for the comments gang. just accepted @SLaks answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `returnVal` callback doesn't actually do anything.

Instead, you need to actually pass a callback that accepts the value:

```
var promise = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {
    method1(4, function(x) { resolve(x); });
  }
);
```

You can also just pass `resolve` itself as the callback:

```
var promise = new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {
    method1(4, resolve);
  }
);
```

Comment: thank you for including the example. seems so elementary, but that's my level at the moment! Cheers.

Comment: @abigwonderful: You're welcome! See also http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/ & sequels.

Answer (score 0):

Your `method1` does return nothing, that's why `x` is undefined. That the `returnVal` callback does return something is insignificant, its return value is simply ignored by `method1`.

You will need to call `resolve` as the callback to make your code work:

```
new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject) {
    var x = method1(4, resolve);
  }
).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val); // undefined
  return val;
});
```

See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572)